# how to show pyspark df with large columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have big pyspark df, with many columns and I need show it correctly. I don't need vertical.
Is there way to show with scrolling?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
display(HTML("<style>pre { white-space: pre !important; }</style>"))
```

And execute `df.show()`,  you will get the scrollbar.

Comment: and you can use df.show(truncate=False) to show all data in each cell

Answer (score 0):

Try with `display(sparkDF)` else the best workaround is

```
sparkDF.limit(5).toPandas().head()
```