# How to clearly see column names and data in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Currently, I am using df.show(2) or df.show(truncate=0) to see all results of a dataframe. But I am getting data  in a scrambled manner. How to neatly align ?

I have close to 15 columns to display and  column names, data  are getting chopped of as below screen shot

[image]

Comment: To truncate the results use df.show(truncate=False), data are getting chopped because you edior doesn't fit the results, copy/paste the result to an editor like vscode or notepad++

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to show pyspark df with large columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72892329/how-to-show-pyspark-df-with-large-columns)

Answer (score 1):

The `show` method takes Boolean True or False for `truncate` param, so you can try doing:

```py
df.show(truncate=False)
```

It might be irrelevant, but if you are using Databricks platform, then it has a `display` method built in, that renders the whole DataFrame in easy to use visual format - more [here](https://www.databricks.com/spark/getting-started-with-apache-spark/dataframes).

Otherwise, you will have to export the data to some third-party tool, like Excel.

Comment: I am using Vs code and I am doing ds.show(2) ,since it has more columns output is getting scrambled any idea how to view it properly?