# Load CSV with PySpark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to read a CSV file with PySpark, but I'm getting this output.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Enem_ETL").getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format('csv') \
.option('header', 'true') \
.option('inferSchema', 'true') \
.load(r'C:\Users\GRUPO BARBOSA\Documents\Python\Eng Dados\enem\microdados_enem_2021\DADOS\MICRODADOS_ENEM_2021.csv')

df.show()
```

The output:

[image]

I don't want these "+--+" lines. How can I remove it?

I tried to set some options like delimiter, encoding, inferSchema... but none of these worked.

Comment: Please post your code and your error as formatted text, not an image. That way they can be more easily found and reproduced by others.

Comment: Have you tried doing just `df.show()` in second cell? I guess your options are correct and data is read correctly, so it's just a matter of how to properly display the DataFrame.

Comment: Use `df.show(false)`

Comment: you can't remove them. it's a jupyter format thing that happens when the number of columns don't fit the width of the notebook

Comment: possible dupe of [how to show pyspark df with large columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72892329/how-to-show-pyspark-df-with-large-columns)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.